# tag <hr /> don't working in bootstrap 4.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tag **'hr'** doesn't work in class **'row'**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">col 1</div>
    <div class="col-4">col 2</div>
    <div class="col-4">col 3</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="col-4">col 1</div>
    <div class="col-4">col 2</div>
    <div class="col-4">col 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It will work if I add style for tag **'hr'** with 'width:100%'

Why do I need to do that? Thanks for reply.

Comment: Don't you have a CSS rule that is overwriting the `<hr>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you give your hr a `col-12` class?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">col 1</div>
    <div class="col-4">col 2</div>
    <div class="col-4">col 3</div>
    <hr class="col-12" />
    <div class="col-4">col 1</div>
    <div class="col-4">col 2</div>
    <div class="col-4">col 3</div>
</div>
```

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

[Grid system - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)